# SharePoint designer "The version of Microsoft SharePoint Foundation ..is more recent than the version of SharePoint Designer that you are using"

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Today i downloaded SharePoint Designer 2013 and i want to connect it to sharepoint online site collection, but when i try to connect to a site i got this message:-

```
The version of Microsoft SharePoint Foundation running on the server is more recent than the version of SharePoint Designer that you are using. You need a more recent version of SharePoint Designer
```

as follow:-

[image]

any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solutions:

In SharePoint designer 2013 Click on the File tab and then click on Account
[image]
In the Account page Click on “Switch Account” as highlighted below.
[image]
Type in the credentials of the site you are trying to open(Make sure it is the right account to access the SharePoint site) and restart your SPD.

If it does not work, try to [clear the SPD cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43113666/how-to-clear-cache-in-sharepoint-designer-site) and repeat the above steps.

If the issue still persists, I would suggest you uninstall and reinstall SPD and try again.

Reference:
[Server error](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/4d404225-c275-4499-a08e-e05a54a89bb9/server-error-the-version-of-microsoft-sharepoint-foundation-running-on-the-server-is-more-recent?forum=sharepointadmin)

[Sharepoint designer error "the version of microsoft sharepoint foundation running on the server"](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-designer-error-the-version-of-microsoft/92ec4ad6-3ffc-40b8-8814-0ef8db4ce7de)